# Incorporating External Content in a Scorm module

Tags: scorm

I'm working on building up a training plan for our Google Apps users.
We subscribe to http://synergyse.com which has interactive training as well as some straight up videos.

Our LMS uses exclusively SCORM to provide the training modules.

I'm trying to figure out the best approach to incorporating the two.
A few approaches I'm thinking about...

1. Provide a "guide" along the way. The SCORM module walks you through which training modules to take from Synergyse. (Obviously it would link out to the synergyse content in the Google Apps interfaces)
2. Direct them to the training modules and then deliver a "Certification test" using a SCORM module

Is there a better way, or more friendly way to incorporate external training content into a SCORM workflow?

Comment: this training does not support SCORM and you're looking to add the necessary calls to make it work with the LMS?  Or are your looking to wrap your content with something to present the non-SCORM training?  It was a little hard to pick out if this was a packaging or content issue.

Comment: +1. More clarity on what the issue you're trying to solve is. Is the problem that the external content is not tracked, or that you need a smoother user journey to get to and from the external content? Or both?

Comment: I recognize that the content I'm presenting isn't SCORM compliant. And I'm not trying to find a way to "jam it in there" either. What I was hoping for was some ideas on how to meld the two. The external content is never going to work inside a SCORM module... but, is there any best practices for when you're creating SCORM training and want to direct people to sites outside the SCORM module? Does that even make sense?

Comment: I guess an easier way to ask this is. I have external training content. It's not SCORM compliant, and it can't be made SCORM compliant. It has to stay where it is. What's my best approach to create a "training plan" that will incorporate this material. Any training that is published and "pushed to users" in our LMS has to be SCORM. What are my options? A simple quiz after they've watched/interacted with the content?

Comment: If you are looking for a simple "I was here" auto score type approach to initialize, set score, completion, success and terminate then there are some options.  If its more robust, and you need some surgical work setting things at certain points like (page navigation, % of video watched etc ...) then its more hands on.  I threw together a Mac/PC packager that can inject the auto score into non-SCORM content on https://cybercussion.com if you want to try it.